# How to create DB with Latin9 locale

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-12

I have a new server running Postgres Linux Version 12.9 (2021-12-13), and I want to create a DB with these options:

```
CREATE DATABASE et_base WITH 
ENCODING 'LATIN9' LC_COLLATE = 'fr_FR.iso885915@euro'
LC_CTYPE = 'fr_FR.iso885915@euro' TEMPLATE=template0.....
```

But I get this error message:

> ERROR:  invalid locale name: "fr_FR.iso885915@euro"

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, this site is only in English. I think I understood enough of your question to translate it for you, sorry if I have edited anything wrong.

Comment: The [Postgres Supported Character Sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/multibyte.html) page says that "ISO885915" is "LATIN1 with Euro and accents", so perhaps you don't need the "@euro" part.

Comment: In 2021? Use the DB in Unicode. Then in your app, you can use just a subset, but you will have just problems on keeping old encoding (as you are experiencing).

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's possible that, at least historically, "fr_FR" would format monetary values in French Francs rather than Euros, independent of the character set. You're right though, that part of the advantage of 8859-15 over 8859-1 is that it includes an encoding of the € symbol.

Comment: It works for me using Postgres 12.9:`et_base       | postgres  | LATIN9   | fr_FR.iso885915@euro | fr_FR.iso885915@euro` What OS and version are you running this on?

Comment: What do you get for `locale -a` on the shell? You should always use UTF8.